# Comparing SQL Server databases and automatic mapping

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, mapping

This is more of a "Would it be possible" question...

If I have 2 databases, 1 database is for an old system (we'll call it v1.0) and the other database is for the new system (v2.0).

Now let's imagine that there has been a data migration between v1.0 and v2.0 but there is no mapping tables or documentation (for reasons I won't go into) and we need to know the integrity of the data.

Is it possible to write a script that could automatically map the tables in each database to a level of inspecting the data and deciding if it's a possible match and produce a table with the results?

So you end up with something like:

```
Source...........|Possible matches  
v1.0.............|v2.0............|v2.0............|v2.0  
table234.columnA |table109.columnX|table63.columnY |table10.columnZ  
table234.columnB |table139.columnX|table13.columnY |table140.columnZ
```

So you'd end up with a source table/column and all the possible tables/columns that it could potentially be.

I know this is a bit of an odd one off request but anyone ever need to do anything like this?

Answer (score 4):

Red Gate Data Compare does the data comparison job very well and concise. You can select tables, columns and event add row based filter to your comparison project.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/

Comment: Upvote from a very satisfied Red Gate user. Very polished commercial tools.  With DataCompare you can match tables and columns as needed and then save that comparison mapping to rerun at any time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a database compare tool like the [DbComparer](http://dbcomparer.com/) . It can help you resolve most of your queries. Its absolutely free too. This will help you understand the differences between the database schemas of the 2 databases.

To compare the two database version, You can check [this link out.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833428%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) You can use the Database comparison Wizard to attain the difference.

A free tool called [CompareData](http://www.zidsoft.com/) is available too.

If you want to pay for it, you can check out [SQL Data Compare 9.0](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/)

Comment: David is asking for data comparisons, not schema comparisons, from what I can read of his question. For example, he wants to know that the text in Customer.Street_Name has moved to Customer_Address.Street_Name, or Customer.Country text has moved to Countries.Description. And, he wants a method or tool that discovers this mapping through comparison of the data contents.

Comment: I realise that he wants to compare the data integrity. But, since these are 2 different databases, the first step will be to check whether these databases have the same tables, sp, etc. In short, compare the schema of the databases to see the difference. Check my updated answer

Comment: I think to clarify a little more. If you had TableX.ColumnA that had "joe bloggs", "jane bloggs", "peter bloggs" and you had TableY.ColumnZ that also contained "joe bloggs", "jane bloggs", "peter bloggs" but there was nothing logically linking them like the Table names Customer or Sys_Customer or something.

Comment: You can specify the table and columns that u need to compare in the data comparers mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

It sounds possible. One idea - you could create a "mapping integrity" view so to speak, but assuming this migration will result in the "version 1" database remaining static moving forward, you could instead create a mapping integrity table and populate it one time through a stored procedure. This would result in the mapping integrity table being faster to query than a view.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of what you're asking is that if you have a field in Schema 1 like Customer.Country, that has values in it "United States", "Canada" and "Mexico", you want a list of all columns in Schema 2 that have the values "United States", "Canada" and "Mexico". Sound right?

Based on my understanding of what you're asking, it could largely depend on what kind of mapping has been done and how complicated it is. Here's some examples, based on some schema change projects I've seen:

**Unioning**: If Schema 1 had Shoe_Customers and Boot_Customers and Schema 2 joined them into one Customers table, then finding the map for Shoe_Customers.Customer_Name would have to look for a *subset* of values in Customers.Name. Similarly, if Schema 1's Customers.Country had been replaced with a Countries generic look up table in Schema 2, and someone populated that table with a full list of countries, then you'd be looking for a subset to match Customers.Country and Countries.Name (or, are they matches?).

**Subsetting**: Taking the opposite approach, if Schema 1 had Customers and Schema 2 broke that into Shoe_Customers and Boot_Customers, then you're only going to find a subset of Schema 1 values in any given column of Schema 2. I'm not sure how you'd define a success case here.

**Cardinality**: If you're trying to track down fairly unique data, like Customer.Name, then you have a pretty high chance of success with an automated approach. Anything with a low level of cardinality is likely to give you more false leads than you'd find worth it. If Gender is M or F, and Discount_Code is A-Z as is Sole_Style and Heel_Style etc..., then tracking this data down through automated data matching is going to be a massive waste of time. This will get worse with numeric data, especially low cardinality data like percentages.

**Data type changes**: I'm guessing you're asking this because it involves hundreds or thousands of column changes, with large quantities of data. If the idea is to compare all "string data" to all other "string data", and all "numeric data" to all other "numeric data", then this is going to be massive. If the schema change *excluded* data type changes (e.g. not allowing: Customer.Country was varchar(15) but now Countries.Name is varchar(50)), then you've got a leg up on the task.

These are the things that are coming to mind at the moment. Your situation may make all of these factors irrelevant, or your situation may have these factors as just the tip of the iceberg. Personally, I'm a little skeptical of a fully automated approach for most situations. My suggestion would be to write a stored procedure that takes two table/column names, one from each schema, and will tell you what coverage of Schema 1 values there is in Schema 2, coverage of Schema 2 values in Schema 1, some kind of cardinality measurements, etc.... Combined with a little human influence, you should be able to some proportion of your columns mapped, probably in less time than a full blown generic solution with lots of dead-ends to pursue.

Good luck,

Terry.